# Jupyter notebook: Package or namespace load failed for 'caret' in loadNamespace

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, r-caret

I was originally going to ask the following question but I figured it out myself and decided to post the following question and answer in case it might help someone with the same issue:

I'm currently working on a project in Jupyter Notebook using R.

Everything was working fine until I try to load caret with `library(caret)` and I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'caret' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, > > .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called 'codetools'
Traceback:

1. library(caret)
2. tryCatch({
.     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
.     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I've tried unistalling and re-installing `caret` in RStudio but that didn't help either. What makes this more infuriating is that in my RStudio everything is working fine, it's just Jypyter notebook that is unable to find `caret`.

Here is my session info FYI:

````
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.0   lattice_0.20-38

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        pillar_1.4.2      compiler_3.6.0    plyr_1.8.4       
 [5] base64enc_0.1-3   iterators_1.0.12  tools_3.6.0       digest_0.6.22    
 [9] uuid_0.1-2        jsonlite_1.6      evaluate_0.14     tibble_2.1.3     
[13] gtable_0.3.0      nlme_3.1-142      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.5      
[17] foreach_1.4.7     IRdisplay_0.7.0   IRkernel_1.0.2    repr_1.0.1       
[21] withr_2.1.2       dplyr_0.8.3       grid_3.6.0        tidyselect_0.2.5 
[25] glue_1.3.1        R6_2.4.1          pbdZMQ_0.3-3      purrr_0.3.3      
[29] magrittr_1.5      scales_1.0.0      codetools_0.2-16  htmltools_0.4.0  
[33] assertthat_0.2.1  timeDate_3043.102 colorspace_1.4-1  munsell_0.5.0    
[37] crayon_1.3.4     
​```
````

Comment: What could have been useful also is your `sessionInfo()` and what message you get when installing `caret` within Jupyter Notebook (it should say where it is installing the package and which dependencies are installed).

Comment: I've added the session info to the question now. And the warning message I get when installing `caret` in Jupyter Notebook is the one I gave in the question. After I got it working in Jupyter, `caret` stopped working in RStudio. So it seems I can't make `caret` work in both programs at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I was expecting it to tell in which library path it would attempt the installation... Do you get the same output with `.libPaths()` in both environment ?

Comment: When executing `.libPaths()` in Jupyter I get the following output:
```'C:/Users/pechingerK/Documents/R/win-library/3.6' 'C:/Users/pechingerK/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Lib/R/library'
```
and when executing the command in RStudio I get:

```"C:/Users/pechingerK/Documents/R/win-library/3.6" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library" 
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by uninstalling `caret` with `remove.packages("caret")` in Jupyter Notebook. I also checked that the package was no longer installed in RStudio.

Then, I re-installed `caret` with `install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)` in Jupyter notebook.

I think what was causing the issue was that somehow Jupyter had not installed `caret`'s dependent packages. From the first error message in the question ,this was `codetools`. And every time I installed the package named in the error, it came up with another package to install. Which made me think that - of course- it hadn't installed any of the dependencies.

`caret` now works in Jupyter Notebook.